# Symfony, encode status text parameter in setStatusCode prcedure

Tags: php, symfony

I have a pretty simple controller with code like this

```
    public function deleteCarrierAction($login)
{
    $settingsService = $this->get('app.settings');
    $result = $settingsService->deleteCarrier($login);
    if (!$result)
    {
        $response->setStatusCode(400, $settingsService->errorInfo);
        return $response;
    }
    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    return $response;
}
```

Where `$settingsService->errorInfo` contains symbols in my national language. How to encode errorInfo text to UTF-8?
When I see errorInfo in Chrome browser's debug console it appears like this:

```
settings:251 POST http://xxxxxxx:8000/delete_carrier/79323317315 400 (ÐÐ° ÐºÑÑÑÐµÑÐ° Ð½Ð°Ð·Ð½Ð°ÑÐµÐ½Ñ Ð·Ð°ÐºÐ°Ð·Ñ. Ð£Ð´Ð°Ð»ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ Ð½ÐµÐ²Ð¾Ð·Ð¼Ð¾Ð¶Ð½Ð¾)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is chrome issue to return info in wrong encoding.

Consider to use keys to describe info and errors, and just if u want to be more readable translate it for example in view:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/i18n.html

or in your service create method to translate error, and use it response:

```
$response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, $settingsService->getTranslatedErrorInfo());
```